# How to do OUTER JOIN in scala

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, dataframe

I havce two data frames : df1 and df2

df1

```
|--- id---|---value---|
|    1    |    23     |
|    2    |    23     |
|    3    |    23     |
|    2    |    25     |
|    5    |    25     |
```

df2

```
|-idValue-|---count---|
|    1    |    33     |
|    2    |    23     |
|    3    |    34     |
|    13   |    34     |
|    23   |    34     |
```

How do I get this ?

```
|--- id--------|---value---|---count---|
|    1         |    23     |    33     |
|    2         |    23     |    23     |
|    3         |    23     |    34     |
|    2         |    25     |    23     |
|    5         |    25     |    null   |
```

I am doing :

```
 val groupedData =  df1.join(df2, $"id" === $"idValue", "outer")
```

But I don't see the last column in the groupedData. Is this correct way of doing ? Or Am I doing any thing wrong ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From your expected output, you need LEFT OUTER JOIN.

```
val groupedData =  df1.join(df2, $"id" === $"idValue", "left_outer").
       select(df1("id"), df1("count"), df2("count")).
       take(10).foreach(println)
```